# Optimizing the rational quadratic kernel function

Tags: python, numpy, performance, optimization, vectorization

Given the following functions, what are some optimizations that can be done to speed up computations?

Yes, I tried using ChatGPT and Bard, the reason I'm mentioning this is that there's a "caveat" to their solutions, `np.nan if (index - i) < 0 else price_feed[index - i]` has to hold. So for each period, I need to check the previous periods, if on the dataframe that period is `index 0`, then it is np.nan, since doing a lookup to the past is nonsense, since 1) it is not possible in live envirioments, 2) you would be looking "into the future".

````py
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, float32, uint32, float64

@jit(
    float64[:](float64[:], uint32, float32, uint32),
    cache=True,
    parallel=True,
    nopython=True,
    target_backend="cuda",
    forceobj=False,
    nogil=True,
)
def rational_quadratic(
    price_feed: np.ndarray,
    lookback: int,
    relative_weight: float,
    start_at_bar: int,
) -> np.ndarray:

    length_of_prices = len(price_feed)
    bars_calculated = start_at_bar + 1

    result = np.zeros(length_of_prices, dtype=float)
    lookback_squared = np.power(lookback, 2)
    denominator = lookback_squared * 2 * relative_weight

    for index in range(length_of_prices):
        current_weight = 0.0
        cumulative_weight = 0.0

        for i in range(bars_calculated):
            y = np.nan if (index - i) < 0 else price_feed[index - i]
            w = np.power(
                1 + (np.power(i, 2) / denominator),
                -relative_weight,
            )
            current_weight += y * w
            cumulative_weight += w

        result[index] = current_weight / cumulative_weight

    return result


def rational_quadratic_wrapper(
    dataframe: DataFrame,
    lookback: int,
    relative_weight: float,
    start_at_bar: int,
    candle_type: str,
) -> DataFrame:

    dataframe = dataframe.copy()
    
    ohlc4_values = dataframe[candle_type].values
    no_filter_values = rational_quadratic(ohlc4_values, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar)
    dataframe["no_filter"] = no_filter_values

    dataframe["yhatdelt2"] = rational_quadratic(
        no_filter_values, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar
    )
    dataframe["smooth"] = dataframe["no_filter"] - (dataframe["no_filter"] - dataframe["yhatdelt2"])
    dataframe["zero_lag"] = dataframe["no_filter"] + (
        dataframe["no_filter"] - dataframe["yhatdelt2"]
    )

    return dataframe


fake_price_data = {'ohlc4': [4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135, 4308.172, 4175.935, 4070.76, 4112.74, 4029.135]}
dates = pd.date_range(start='2017-08-17', periods=36, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_data, index=dates)

results = rational_quadratic_optimized(debug_df, 8, 1, 5, "ohlc4")
print(results)

# Make sure your optimization matches the results dataframe output

# I tried using ChatGPT and Bard, all of their solutions break the constraints or generate a ```shape error``` when doing cross multiplications with the ```relative weight```. Wish you luck in the challenge!
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [numba](/questions/tagged/numba) to optimize this operation:

```py
from numba import njit, prange


@njit(parallel=True)
def rational_quadratic_numba(price_feed, out, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar):
    lookback_squared = np.power(lookback, 2)
    denominator = lookback_squared * 2 * relative_weight

    for i in prange(start_at_bar, len(price_feed)):
        current_weight = 0.0
        cumulative_weight = 0.0

        for j in range(start_at_bar + 1):
            y = price_feed[i - j]
            w = np.power(
                1 + (np.power(j, 2) / denominator),
                -relative_weight,
            )
            current_weight += y * w
            cumulative_weight += w

        out[i] = current_weight / cumulative_weight
```

---

The whole script (only `no_filter_2` is computed with new function for simplicity):

```py
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

from numba import njit, prange


@njit(parallel=True)
def rational_quadratic_numba(price_feed, out, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar):
    lookback_squared = np.power(lookback, 2)
    denominator = lookback_squared * 2 * relative_weight

    for i in prange(start_at_bar, len(price_feed)):
        current_weight = 0.0
        cumulative_weight = 0.0

        for j in range(start_at_bar + 1):
            y = price_feed[i - j]
            w = np.power(
                1 + (np.power(j, 2) / denominator),
                -relative_weight,
            )
            current_weight += y * w
            cumulative_weight += w

        out[i] = current_weight / cumulative_weight


def rational_quadratic(
    price_feed: np.ndarray,
    lookback: int,
    relative_weight: float,
    start_at_bar: int,
) -> np.ndarray:
    length_of_prices = len(price_feed)
    bars_calculated = start_at_bar + 1

    result = np.zeros(length_of_prices, dtype=float)
    lookback_squared = np.power(lookback, 2)
    denominator = lookback_squared * 2 * relative_weight

    for index in range(length_of_prices):
        current_weight = 0.0
        cumulative_weight = 0.0

        for i in range(bars_calculated):
            y = np.nan if (index - i) < 0 else price_feed[index - i]
            w = np.power(
                1 + (np.power(i, 2) / denominator),
                -relative_weight,
            )
            current_weight += y * w
            cumulative_weight += w

        result[index] = current_weight / cumulative_weight

    return result


def rational_quadratic_wrapper(
    dataframe: DataFrame,
    lookback: int,
    relative_weight: float,
    start_at_bar: int,
    candle_type: str,
) -> DataFrame:
    dataframe = dataframe.copy()

    ohlc4_values = dataframe[candle_type].values

    no_filter_values = rational_quadratic(
        ohlc4_values, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar
    )
    dataframe["no_filter"] = no_filter_values

    dataframe["no_filter_2"] = np.nan
    rational_quadratic_numba(
        ohlc4_values,
        dataframe["no_filter_2"].values,
        lookback,
        relative_weight,
        start_at_bar,
    )

    dataframe["yhatdelt2"] = rational_quadratic(
        no_filter_values, lookback, relative_weight, start_at_bar
    )
    dataframe["smooth"] = dataframe["no_filter"] - (
        dataframe["no_filter"] - dataframe["yhatdelt2"]
    )
    dataframe["zero_lag"] = dataframe["no_filter"] + (
        dataframe["no_filter"] - dataframe["yhatdelt2"]
    )

    return dataframe


fake_price_data = {
    "ohlc4": [
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
        4308.172,
        4175.935,
        4070.76,
        4112.74,
        4029.135,
    ]
}
dates = pd.date_range(start="2017-08-17", periods=36, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame(fake_price_data, index=dates)

results = rational_quadratic_wrapper(df, 8, 1, 5, "ohlc4")
print(results)
```

Prints:

```
               ohlc4    no_filter  no_filter_2    yhatdelt2       smooth     zero_lag
2017-08-17  4308.172          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-18  4175.935          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-19  4070.760          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-20  4112.740          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-21  4029.135          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-22  4308.172  4164.845721  4164.845721          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-23  4175.935  4146.820891  4146.820891          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-24  4070.760  4129.994743  4129.994743          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-25  4112.740  4135.491538  4135.491538          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-26  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106          NaN          NaN          NaN
2017-08-27  4308.172  4164.845721  4164.845721  4143.152441  4143.152441  4186.539001
2017-08-28  4175.935  4146.820891  4146.820891  4140.761712  4140.761712  4152.880071
2017-08-29  4070.760  4129.994743  4129.994743  4138.115818  4138.115818  4121.873668
2017-08-30  4112.740  4135.491538  4135.491538  4138.839640  4138.839640  4132.143436
2017-08-31  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106  4135.872389  4135.872389  4103.305823
2017-09-01  4308.172  4164.845721  4164.845721  4143.152441  4143.152441  4186.539001
2017-09-02  4175.935  4146.820891  4146.820891  4140.761712  4140.761712  4152.880071
2017-09-03  4070.760  4129.994743  4129.994743  4138.115818  4138.115818  4121.873668
2017-09-04  4112.740  4135.491538  4135.491538  4138.839640  4138.839640  4132.143436
2017-09-05  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106  4135.872389  4135.872389  4103.305823
2017-09-06  4308.172  4164.845721  4164.845721  4143.152441  4143.152441  4186.539001
2017-09-07  4175.935  4146.820891  4146.820891  4140.761712  4140.761712  4152.880071
2017-09-08  4070.760  4129.994743  4129.994743  4138.115818  4138.115818  4121.873668
2017-09-09  4112.740  4135.491538  4135.491538  4138.839640  4138.839640  4132.143436
2017-09-10  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106  4135.872389  4135.872389  4103.305823
2017-09-11  4029.135  4115.210393  4115.210393  4134.323269  4134.323269  4096.097517
2017-09-12  4308.172  4121.092758  4121.092758  4127.424441  4127.424441  4114.761075
2017-09-13  4175.935  4123.912211  4123.912211  4123.931166  4123.931166  4123.893256
2017-09-14  4070.760  4123.022699  4123.022699  4122.861083  4122.861083  4123.184315
2017-09-15  4112.740  4123.049833  4123.049833  4121.113987  4121.113987  4124.985679
2017-09-16  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106  4121.096805  4121.096805  4118.081408
2017-09-17  4308.172  4164.845721  4164.845721  4129.714298  4129.714298  4199.977144
2017-09-18  4175.935  4146.820891  4146.820891  4134.182404  4134.182404  4159.459379
2017-09-19  4070.760  4129.994743  4129.994743  4135.111035  4135.111035  4124.878451
2017-09-20  4112.740  4135.491538  4135.491538  4136.988124  4136.988124  4133.994952
2017-09-21  4029.135  4119.589106  4119.589106  4135.872389  4135.872389  4103.305823
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit

dates = pd.date_range(start="2017-08-17", periods=36_000, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"ohlc4": 50 + np.random.random(len(dates)) * 100}, index=dates)

t1 = timeit(
    "rational_quadratic(df['ohlc4'].values, 8, 1, 5)", number=1, globals=globals()
)

t2 = timeit(
    "df['no_filter_2']=np.nan;rational_quadratic_numba(df['ohlc4'].values, df['no_filter_2'].values, 8, 1, 5)",
    number=1,
    globals=globals(),
)

print(f"Time normal = {t1}")
print(f"Time numba =  {t2}")`
```

This prints on my computer AMD 5700x:

```
Time normal = 0.3848473190009827
Time numba =  0.000804967996373307
```

Comment: Thank you for the time to write your answer, unfortunately, I had numba already on my local code, I forgot to add it here, I have now updated it with various arguments on the wrapper. Anything I might be missing there? The optimization I'm lookinfor is mostly on the "for loops" nuances

Comment: @Corfucinas So, it's the numba method slow?

Comment: It is magnitudes faster, but I need to call this function with a HUGE amount of data...so faster would be amaizing.

Comment: @Corfucinas So look at my example I have in the answer - I slightly optimized the for-loop, preallocated the array outside the numba function + used the parallelization.

Comment: Actually, you are correct, I had an inheritance problem and your function did not got called down the line, I tried it and it is indeed an improvement worth of the points